# LI active data filter not applying on initial page load

Tags: css, html-lists

I've managed to splice together this site for my wedding. I'm banging my head against the wall because I just don't know enough to get this done:

I can set the `active` attribute on the small gallery section of the site, but the data filter is not filtering the contents to the set active filter on initial page load only.

*Example*: I can set the active `li` to any section, and it will highlight it, but it displays all the photos and does not filter by the defined data filters.

Below is the **CSS** let me know if you need anything else.

```
/* =========================================================== 
        13. Small Gallery
    ============================================================ */
 #wedding-gallery {
   padding-bottom: 0;
 }
 #wedding-gallery h3.section-title:before {
   margin-left: -17px;
   font-size: 38px;
   content: "\e00c";
 }
 #gallery-filter {
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 90px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
 }
 #gallery-filter li {
   display: inline-block;
   line-height: 14px;
   margin: 0 5px;
 }
 #gallery-filter li:last-child {
   border-right: 0;
 }
 #gallery-filter li a {
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #666666;
   padding: 8px 15px;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
 #gallery-filter li a:hover,
 #gallery-filter li.active a {
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 8px 15px;
   border-radius: 6px;
 }
 #gallery-wrapper > div {
   width: 25%;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
 }
 #gallery-wrapper > div img {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
 }
 #gallery-wrapper > .block.gallery img {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   top: 0;
 }
 #gallery-wrapper > .block img {
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-transition: all 700ms;
   -moz-transition: all 700ms;
   transition: all 700ms;
   transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
   -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
 }
 #gallery-wrapper .block .portfolio-hover,
 #gallery-wrapper .block .video-hover {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   text-align: center;
   background: rgba(255, 140, 137, 0.7);
   -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease 0s;
   -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease 0s;
   transition: opacity 400ms ease 0s;
   cursor: pointer;
   z-index: 5;
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 }
 #gallery-wrapper .block .portfolio-info {
   position: absolute;
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 #gallery-wrapper .block:hover .portfolio-hover,
 #gallery-wrapper .block:hover .video-hover {
   opacity: 1;
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=95)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=95);
 }
 #gallery-wrapper .portfolio-title {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 0 35px;
 }
 #gallery-wrapper .portfolio-title span {
   display: block;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 12px;
 }
 .load-more {
   margin-top: 55px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .load-more a {
   color: #D9C6B1;
 }
 /* Portfolio isotope Animation
    ======================== */
 .isotope,
 .isotope .isotope-item {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -ms-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
 }
 .isotope {
   -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
   -moz-transition-property: height, width;
   -ms-transition-property: height, width;
   -o-transition-property: height, width;
   transition-property: height, width;
 }
 .isotope .isotope-item {
   -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
   -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
   -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
   -o-transition-property: -o-transform, opacity;
   transition-property: transform, opacity;
 }
 /* =========================================================== 
        14.  Twitter 
    ============================================================ */
 #twitter h3.section-title:before {
   content: "\e00d";
   font-size: 40px;
 }
 #twitter .vibe {
   margin-bottom: 0;
 }
 #twitter .tweet {
   font-size: 14px;
   margin-top: 25px;
 }
 #twitter .time {
   display: block;
   font-size: 12px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 #twitter .follow {
   display: block;
   margin-top: 55px;
   font-weight: 700;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #D9C6B1;
 }
 #twitter .follow:hover {
   color: #FF8C89;
 }
 /* =========================================================== 
        15.  Gift Registry 
    ============================================================ */
 #gift-registry h3.section-title:before {
   content: "\e009";
 }
 .small-box {
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 25px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
 }
 .small-box li {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 160px;
   height: 150px;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 7px;
   background: #fff;
 }
 .small-box li a.product {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   line-height: 130px;
   border: 1px solid #efe7df;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .small-box li a img {
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
 /* 5.1.  Gift Money 
    ============================================================ */
 .small-box .money {
   border: 1px solid #efe7df;
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 25px;
 }
 .small-box .amount {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 20px;
   font: 28px/32px'Playfair Display', serif;
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: 700;
   color: #FF8C89;
 }
 .small-box .donate {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 35px;
   left: 27px;
   z-index: 999;
   color: #D9C6B1;
 }
 .small-box .donate:hover {
   color: #FF8C89;
 }
 .small-box .donate:active {
   top: 76px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your custom.js, actually -- here's the part relevant to that gallery:

```
$('#gallery-filter a').click(function() {
        $('#gallery-filter li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Basically, that's the declaration of how those filter buttons on the gallery work. When clicked, they call $container.isotope, which is what actually handles the filtering and hiding of inactive elements. So if you want to set that on page load, you can invoke the same method but pass it a different filter. Does that make sense, or should I get into it in more detail?

EDIT: Adding more info here.
Since this whole js file is being called on document ready, this is pretty simple - you should be able to immediately "fake" a click on the button you want. Try putting this line in custom.js, immediately after the code above:

```
$('#gallery-filter a[data-filter=".FriendsandFamily"]').trigger('click');
```

What that should do is simulate a click on the Friends and Family button, making it active. You can do the same for the other tabs by changing the "data-filter" part of that line to match what's on them in the html. (If that doesn't work, let me know.)

Comment: Jack, thanks so much for your quick response! I'm trying to get this up tonight so I'd appreciate a ~facepalm~ step by step. So I have the code in my custom.js in front of me here but guess I'm not understand which part to change to what. As you see on the site, there's three defined filters now, but I'm not seeing where to define it. If I define it on the HTML, if is simply ignored,makes sense as you said it's in the js/isotope. To be specific as an example, so I change it later. If I wanted to have the default view filter on the items tagged as "KimmeandChris" where and what would I change?

Comment: Thanks for putting up with the little guys like us =)

Comment: So to be more clear, and I know this is silly to people who understand how it works, I thought putting the class-active under the <li class="active"><a href="#" data-filter=".KimmieandChris">Kimmie & Chris</a> would "call" the data filter. Clearly it isn't and I just don't get how it works.

Comment: It's actually sort of the reverse - calling the data filter is what sets the "active" class. See the third line in the code snippet up there? Ends in " .addClass("active")? That's where that happens. The part after it is the function for the actual filtering. What you would need to do is basically copy that block and have it run on page load, but with a filter specifically set - give me a minute and I'll write out an example.

Comment: Jack, you are the man! That worked perfectly and I tested it as well with the other defined categories. I thousand thanks - truly!